# About redirect log in rsyslog.conf

Tags: services, rsyslog

what is the difference between this 2 lines:

```
mail.warn           -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err            /var/log/mail.err
```

(with and without the `-`)

and who i redirect a syslog msg from a host to a specific file?
ex: `192.168.0.1` to `/var/log/192.168.0.1.log` ?

Answer (score 2):

The `-` means that file are written normally to the log file, so buffered.  Without the `-` the file is flushed at every line, so in case of power problem, every line was already saved to disk.